# If … Then statement for correcting angular measurements

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a script that automatically corrects angular orientation measurements to within the 0-360 range.  Every time I Run my code I get a run-time error 13 Type Mismatch though.  When I ask to debug it highlights the Then section of the function but I don't know specifically what it wants me to change.

```
 Dim k As Integer
    For k = 4 To 1004
    If Cells(k, 5).Value > 360 Then Cells(k, 5).Value = Cells(k, 5).Value - 360
    If Cells(k, 5).Value < 0 Then Cells(k, 5).Value = Cells(k, 5).Value + 360
Next k
```

Comment: What's the value of the cell when it errors? Presumably not a number.

Comment: Have you tried the `Mod` operator?

Comment: I thought the IF THEN function would be better since most of the measurements will fall within the 0-360 range so I only need a correction on those falling outside those ranges.

Comment: All of the values for that column are numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can cover both corrections with Abs and Mod.

```
Dim k As Integer
For k = 4 To 1004
    Cells(k, 5).Value = Abs(Cells(k, 5).Value Mod 360)
Next k
```

If -15° should be 345° and not 15° then,

```
Dim k As Integer
For k = 4 To 1004
    Cells(k, 5).Value = Abs(Cells(k, 5).Value Mod 360 - (Cells(k, 5).Value < 0) * 360)
Next k
```